# Unit testing class with own coroutine scope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class that looks something like

```
class Foo {
  private val scope = Job() + Dispatchers.IO
  val emissions = PublishSubject.create<Bar>()

  fun doSomething() {
    scope.launch {
      // Do a whole bunch of work...
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) emissions.onNext(bar)
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to come up with a way to unit test it. I've tried making the scope injectable and writing something like

```
@Test fun testFoo() = runBlockingTest {
  Dispatchers.setMain(TestCoroutineDispatcher())
  val foo = Foo(this)
  foo.doSomething()
  foo.emissions.assertStuff()
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. The assertion happens before the coroutine inside `doSomething()` has finished.

I've also tried making this dispatchers injectable, providing `Dispatchers.Unconfined`, but that didn't help either. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: Does it have to be a `PublishSubject`?

Comment: Needs to be a `Subject`, `Relay`,` Channel` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to expose the job for public API, you can try

```
class Foo {
  private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO)
  val emissions = PublishSubject.create<Bar>()

  fun doSomething() = scope.launch {
    // Do a whole bunch of work...
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { emissions.onNext(bar) }
  }
}

class Test {
  private val testFoo = Foo()
  private val testObserver: TestObserver<Bar> = TestObserver.create()

  @BeforeEach
  fun setUp() {
    testFoo.emissions.subscribe(testObserver)
  }

  @Test fun testFoo() {
    runBlockingTest {
      Dispatchers.setMain(TestCoroutineDispatcher())
      testFoo.doSomething().join()
      testObserver.assertValue(bar)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exposing a `Job` means that external callers can cancel the coroutine started by `launch`, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Testing asynchronous code can be done well with this library: [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/) ([or its kotlin extension](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Kotlin))

You would write something like:

```
@Test fun testFoo() {

  val foo = Foo()

  foo.doSomething()

  await().atMost(5, MILLIS).until(/* your check like - foo.emissions.onNext(bar) */);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. That would work, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution with blocking dispatchers.